Merge dataframes with same column name
I have multiple dataframes that are stored in dataframelist, i need to take a certain column let's say ['d'] from each dataframe and put it in a new defined dataframe, but to put them right beside each other, in order to calculate the mean of each row by the end. how to do that in python.
dataFrameList = [df1,df2,df3,df4,..dfn]

All dfs has the same number and names of columns let's say a,b,c,d,e,f,g but different number of rows (different length) df1 has 115 row, df2 has 220 rows, df3 has 90 rows and so on.
newDataFrame=pd.DataFrame() was defined to put the wanted column d from each dataFrame and put it here.
d1,d2,d3,d4,....dn
but they must be right each other, in order to calculate the mean of each row.
How to do that?
newDataFrame=(d1  d2  d3  d4  ... dn)
               2   5   7  8   .... 1
               3   4    8 9   .... 2
               .
               .
               .  
               Nan 9  Nan 15 ...9 


import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(2,4), 'b': range(2,4),   'c': range(2,4),    'b': range(2,4)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(5,10),'b': range(5,10),  'c': range(5,10),   'b': range(5,10)})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(7,11),'b': range(7,11),  'c': range(7,11),   'b': range(7,11)})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(8,13),'b': range(8,13),  'c': range(8,13),   'b': range(8,13)})

merge_on_col = "b"
use_dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
column_names = [f"{merge_on_col}{i}" for i in range(1,len(use_dfs)+1)]
newDataFrame = pd.concat([d[c] for d,c in zip(use_dfs,[merge_on_col]*len(use_dfs))], axis=1, keys=column_names)

    

Output:



b1
b2
b3
b4




2
5
7
8


3
6
8
9


nan
7
9
10


nan
8
10
11


nan
9
nan
12




I tried the previous suggestion, but it appears this table:
A                        B                               C
A                        E                               Nan
a                         r                               Nan
A                        Nan                           Nan
a                        Nan                           Nan
Nan                   Nan                            7
Nan                    Nan                           8
Nan                    Nan                           9
Nan                    Nan                           Nan

@Na.Az could you provide sample code of your dfs, so I know what I need to work with.

'def createNewDataFrame(DataFrameList):
aList = []
bList = []
for df in DataFrameList:
aList.append(df['a'])
bList.append(df['b'])
DataFramea = pd.concat(aList, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
DataFrameb = pd.concat(bList, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
DataFramea.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
DataFrameb.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
return DataFramea, DataFrameb '

They must be right each other, in order to calculate the mean of each row. And that is not what is I am getting. Some of them are beside of each other and others are sliding down.

I meant edit you original question. And  add dataframes, similar to the one in my code:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('AaAa'),'B': list('BbBb'),'C': list('CcCc')})

@Na.Az, I've updated my code, to extract the same column form multiple dataframes .
